# MATE 19.04 Alert Volume mute option disabled

Tags: sound, ubuntu-mate

MATE up to date with 19.04

The check button for 'Mute' on the Alert Volume option of the Sounds Preferences dialog is grayed out.

This was previously working, has happened sometime in the last week of daily updates.

Comment: 19.10 is not released yet, you cannot expect any support here.

Comment: @marosg           Ooops. Thanks.  Typo. It is really 19.04. Early morning here....

Comment: @StephenBoston Consider to ask on https://ubuntu-mate.community/ and/or report bug to launchpad.